# Scale up UITextView's layer with it's contents without losing quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

So, I want to scale up `UITextView`'s `layer` with its text inside and save that as an image without losing quality. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should scale `font` property of your `UITextView`(actually `size` of the `font`)?

Comment: What you are suggesting maybe the way to achieve what I want, but that doesn't answer the question.